# How to generate all 2d arrays of row permutations in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, combinations

There is an array:

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4]]
```

How can I generate a list of arrays of all row-permutations?
I expect a result like:

```
[[[1,2],
  [3,4]],
 [[1,2],
  [4,3]],
 [[2,1],
  [4,3]],
 [[2,1],
  [3,4]]]
```

It is important that values from the first row do not mix with values from second or any other row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for `n` rows only difference is you get a list of tuples:

```
from itertools import product, permutations

[*product(*[permutations(row) for row in matrix])]
# For no duplicates:
[*product(*[set(permutations(row)) for row in matrix])]
```

Comment: what if my input array has 'n' rows?

Comment: @PoczciwyKorsarz Just what I was wondering) - see the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Because of my NumPy array is boolean (there was a lot of repetitions) and I wanted to get NumPy array back, I changed your code a little to the following form:
allPossibleMatrices = [np.array(_) for _ in [*product(*[set(permutations(row)) for row in matrix2d])]]

Comment: @PoczciwyKorsarz Ok - if you're using numpy simply `np.array([*product(*[permutations(row) for row in matrix])])` should work too )